# Component to edit part of parent's state

Tags: reactjs

Ok I am studying React.JS now. Consider the following situation. There is a root component holding the model as state. One of its children is a complex control responsible for editing part of the model. There are some rules: some user's actions modify the part in one way (to be specific, sets a list to contain exactly one clicked item), other actions modify it in other way (like, simply add that item to the list). Those rules, of course, are not imposed by business logics, it's just the way I designed the particular child component. Now I have to decide how to connect the child's UI elements to the model and vice versa.

1) I can make the child stateless. Make it accept the current model state as props, render its UI according to that props, and upon click, send the parent an event (via some callback in props) "hey I've been clicked this way". The parent can examine the event and either apply setState(model=>replace_list_single_entry(model,event.id)), or setState(model=>add_entry_to_list(model,event.id)).
**Drawback**: the parent has to know much about logic specific to a component implementation, while actually I should be able to switch to another component with another implementation. So much for encapsulation, component-driven design, and low coupling.

2) I could make the component calculate a new state for parent (at least in some form, maybe not exactly one which is in the model), send it to some props.onChange, and then the parent could simply setState to accomodate this calculated state.
The severe **drawback** as I see it is, since setState is asynchronous and can be batched, an event loss might occur. Look, the child interprets the user's actions as "add ID1 to list", takes its props.list, makes another list of it and of the ID1, and sends that list to a parent, which makes setState; while that setState is still pending, the user makes another click to add yet another ID2, but the child's props.list is still the same, so the child sends the parent a new calculated list containing ID2 but not ID1. The parent calls setState with this new list and voila, eventually ID1 is lost from the list.

3) I could send the parent not the state calculated from my props, but state calculator. The parent applies this calculator to some "props" object, which it populates from the current state in the same way as if to pass to children's props. (I mean, this may be simply some property from the model, but may be something pre-processed) The resulting "props" are then re-integrated into the model.
**Drawback**: it looks overcomplexified. But maybe that's the way to go, actually.

4) I could make the component stateful, have its own state describing its UI controls, and after each set state completion, send the updated state to the parent. This however is **no different** from approach (2) in sense of drawbacks, and adds some more concerns - admittedly, quite solveable, - like, keeping internal state eventually-consistent with parent's state.

So, what is the proper way to do the trick?

Comment: Even though I agree about the drawbacks, I think that option 1) is usually the way to go. Maybe [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) could be a good option for you.

Comment: Seriously, guys, no one has that sort of components in their apps? Or no one has a solution any better than (1) and they don't want to admit it? :) Except César Landesa, that is.

Answer (score 0):

It really does not make any sense to me.
I mean, the pattern "`<Child onChange="{event=>this.setState(event.data)}>`"> (or something similar) is SO common, everyone rushes to suggest it when some newbie asks "how do I affect parent's state in a child?". But it's enigmatic how everyone is silent when I say "this approach has major drawbacks, how do I avoid them?" How do they people write their code, then?

OK the only solution, given that no one experienced user could give me an exhaustive answer, seems to be "don't make a parent's state dependent on children, make components only responsible for non-overlapping sections of the model, instead of mapping children to a subsection of what's already mapped to a parent".

Even despite such an approach is actually not a decomposition.